# How can I specify a ViewModel class within a class in XAML

Tags: xaml, viewmodel

I have some XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:SmartCubeMobile;assembly=XFMultiPicker"
             xmlns:xfMultiPicker="clr-namespace:XFMultiPicker;assembly=XFMultiPicker"
             x:Class="XFMultiPicker.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <xfMultiPicker:MultiPickerView x:TypeArguments="model:AddressItem1"
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableItems}"
                                       SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

with the code behind as:

```
namespace SmartCubeMobile
{
    public class AddressItem1
    {
        internal string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class FinanceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public class AddressItem2
        {
            internal string Text { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I modify the XAML x:TypeArguments line to 'point to' AddressItem2?  Nothing seems to work e.g. "model:FinanceViewModel.AddressItem2" fails as does everything else.  Does anybody have any ideas? Thank you kindly in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround - don't need this twaddle anymore